# How can I inject a testing value for a Spring Batch configuration class?

Tags: integration-testing, spring-batch, spring-test

I have a Spring Boot / Batch application and would like to write several integration tests. The batch has a FlatFileItemReader and pulls in the file to be read in via yml configuration file. Here's the batch config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration { 

    @Value("${file}")
    private File file;

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<MyClass> reader(LineMapper<MyClass> lineMapper) {

        FlatFileItemReader<MyClass> flatFileItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<MyClass>();
        flatFileItemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(file));
        final int NUMBER_OF_HEADER_LINES = 1;
        flatFileItemReader.setLinesToSkip(NUMBER_OF_HEADER_LINES);
        flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
        return flatFileItemReader;
    }
```

The integration test class for testing the reader is:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = LoadApplication.class)
@TestExecutionListeners( { DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class StepScopeTestExecutionListenerIntegrationTests {

    @Autowired
    private ItemReader<MyClass> reader;

    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder testFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Bean
    public StepExecution getStepExection() {
        StepExecution execution = MetaDataInstanceFactory.createStepExecution();
        return execution;
    }

    @Test
    public void testGoodData() throws Exception {

        try {
            File testFile = testFolder.newFile();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(testFile, "UTF-8");
            writer.println("a,b,c");
            writer.println("1,2,3");
            writer.close();
            //ReflectionTestUtils.setField(someObject, "file", testFile);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        assertNotNull(reader.read());
    }

}
```

In the above test code, what should someObject be set to? Or is there some other way to inject the test file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reader has already been created before the call to testGoodData. Simply override the resource that was set on the reader.

That is, replace

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(someObject, "file", testFile);
```

with this line of code

```
reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(testFile));
```